# What special powers does cabinet have in Australia?

Tags: political-system, australia

A serving member getting a position in cabinet is often talked about in the media. What does it actually mean?

Comment: Please research before asking questions. Questions that can be answered by a Google search are not good questions for Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

[This Wikipedia article explains it all rather nicely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_of_Australia). It was also the first hit when I googled "Australian Politics Cabinet".

Sorry about the rather short answer, but the most basic research would have answered it.